# Как изучить работу в командной строке Windows?

Tags: cmd, командная-строка

я могу использовать сухие справочные материалы по cmd, однако мне кажется, что есть более лучшие способы изучения работы в cmd.
Интересует такая книга (или курс), которая подходит новичкам. Это основной пункт.

p.s. будет гигантским плюсом, если предложенные материалы бесплатны.

Comment: https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/8/9/58911986-D4AD-4695-BF63-F734CD4DF8F2/ws-commands.pdf Подробный туториал в этом пдф

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/introduction-to-powershell/